# Extract an 8 digits number from a string with additional conditions

Tags: regex, vba, string, extract

I need to extract a number from a string with several conditions.

1. It has to start with 1-9, not with 0, and it will have 8 digits. Like 23242526 or 65478932
2. There will be either an empty space or a text variable before it. Like MMX: 23242526 or bgr65478932
3. It could have come in rare cases: 23,242,526
4. It ends with an emty space or a text variable.

Here are several examples:

- From **RE: Markitwire: 120432889: Mx: 24,693,059** i need to get **24693059**
- From **Automatic reply: Auftrag zur Übertragung IRD Ref-Nr. MMX_23497152** need to get **23497152**
- From **FW: CGMSE 2019-2X A1AN XS2022418672 Contract 24663537** need to get **24663537**
- From **RE: BBVA-MAD    MMX_24644644 + MMX_24644645** need to get **24644644, 24644645**

Right now I'm using the regexextract function(found it on this web-site), which extracts any number with 8 digits starting with 2. However it would also extract a number from, let's say, this expression TGF00023242526, which is incorrect. Moreover, I don't know how to add additional conditions to the code.

```
=RegexExtract(A11, ""(2\d{7})\b"", ", ")
```

Thank you in advance.

```
Function RegexExtract(ByVal text As String, _
                      ByVal extract_what As String, _
                      Optional seperator As String = "") As String
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim result As String
Dim allMatches As Object
Dim RE As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
RE.Pattern = extract_what
RE.Global = True
RE.IgnoreCase = True
Set allMatches = RE.Execute(text)
For i = 0 To allMatches.Count - 1
    For j = 0 To allMatches.Item(i).SubMatches.Count - 1
        result = result & seperator & allMatches.Item(i).SubMatches.Item(j)
    Next
Next
If Len(result) <> 0 Then
    result = Right(result, Len(result) - Len(seperator))
End If
RegexExtract = result
End Function
```

Comment: Try  `(?:[\D0]|^)(2\d{7})\b`

Comment: How about [`(?:^|[^\d,])([1-9](?:,?\d){7})(?![\d,])`](https://regex101.com/r/r2NWBp/1) and grab capture of first [group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may create a custom boundary using a non-capturing group before the pattern you have:

```
(?:[\D0]|^)(2\d{7})\b
^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The `(?:[\D0]|^)` part matches either a non-digit (`\D`) or `0` or (`|`) start of string (`^`).

Comment: It seems to work.Thank you! 
Is it also possible to adjust the search for all numbers from 1 to 9? Cause if I go with \d{8}) it will not exclude 0. And, moreover, the 3-4 digit numbers would pump up. =)

Comment: You could try `[1-9]{7}` instead of `\d{7}`.

Comment: @levanski You might want `[1-9]\d{7}`, or see SJR's comment.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to also match 8 digits in values like 23,242,526 and start with a digit 1-9 you might use

```
\b[1-9](?:,?\d){7}\b
```

- `\b` Word boundary
- `[1-9]` Match the firstdigit 1-9
- `(?:,?\d){7}` Repeat 7 times matching an optional comma and a digit
- `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iKdSCz/1)

Then you could afterwards replace the comma's with an empty string.